# Similar sp_execute events in SQL Server 2014 Express trace

Tags: sql-server, profiling

We have an application which uses SQL Server 2014 Express database.

One of the employees complains about poor performance. Network is fine, server CPU - memory - disk load is fine, everything seems to be fine.

I tried to profile the database, but I am not a SQL expert at all.

But I've noticed something weird, in my opinion: there are groups of several similar (sometimes consecutive) `sp_execute` events in the trace, with high (and increasing) duration.

Like this:

[image: SQL Server Profiler trace]

`exec sp_execute 30,112768`, starting from duration 89, skyrockets, in a few steps, to 14453 (which, I suppose, is 14.5 seconds to execute?), featuring the very same "binary data".

What could this possibly indicate? Would it be reasonable to contemplate that the client asks for some info, doesn't receive (or process) it properly, repeats the same query, then again, again and again, effectively "clogging" the server queue in some way?

What can be done to extract more information from the traces?

Thanks a lot!

I tried to profile SQL Server Express database. SQL Server Profiler trace shows strange repeating queries.

I was expecting to understand and interpret the collected results.

Comment: The symptom of increasing durations could be a paginated query based on row number. Check the  preceding `sp_prepare` to see the query.

Comment: You are right, looks like these are the queries sent by a grid component getting more data to display. Pretty slow component..

Thank you for your guidance!